# How to pull in an already generated ConfigMap to a new pod without regenerating the configmap?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a kustomization file that's generating a ConfigMap and behaving as expected. I need to be able to create a new pod that pulls in the environment variables from that same configMap without regenerating the configMap.
In other words, I'm having to do this:

```
envFrom:
    - configMapRef:
        name: config-name-HASH
```

but I want to do this:

```
envFrom:
    - configMapRef:
        name: config-name
```

without needing to regenerate the ConfigMap with kustomize. 
 I've found PodPresets which would seem to be the fix, but that's in Alpha, so it's not good for my organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. While ConfigMap volumes update in-place and automatically (so you could switch that and make your app re-read the file when it updates), env vars pulled from a ConfigMap (or Secret, all of this applies to both) are only checked when the pod is launched. The usual workaround is to put a checksum or generation ID of your configmap as an annotation in the pod template which will automatically trigger a rolling update through the Deployment, StatefulSet, or DaemonSet controllers.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear - pulling the env vars when the pod is launched is exactly what I need. I can do it using configMapRef: name: config-HASH, but having to check the current value of the HASH suffix doesn't seem like the correct approach

Comment: Kustomize should take care of that for you. You just put it without the suffix and after a `kustomize build` you should see it replaced with the current hash-stamped name.

Comment: Well, the ConfigMapGenerator is on a different kustomization file, so it's generated for one set of pods, then I want to create a new pod that uses the same config map as the other pods. For new config maps that are generated, it works, but for the ones that were generated previously it's not pulling in the hash.

Comment: You have to put them all in one Kustomization tree.

Comment: What I have is a standard set of pods, but users can start new pods with their own volumes. I guess I could add the new pods kustomization file to the standard Kustomization tree, and the old pods won't be affected since there's no explicit change?